# Editing a nested list inside a viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I am working on an MVC3 project and currently i'm strugling with a list inside my viewmodel. I want to be able to add items to the list without doing a post(back) of my main view. I want the viewmodel to contain the items from my list when i press the submit button.

What is the best way to accomplish this functionality?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was originally written for MVC2 but works in MVC 3 and 4.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

**Update**

If you do not want to use @Html.BeginCollectionItem you do not have to.  Using the following will work equally well:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    @* 
        You can replace this line with whatever you require but
        for simplicity I prefer to create an editor template for the sub type
    *@
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i])      
}
```

Comment: So what you are telling me, is that you need an extention to accomplish this behavior? I will test this example, but its hard to believe that there isn't an other way.

Comment: Are you referring to the BeginCollectionItem? You could alternatively use a for loop.  I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, but the update you supplied is not what i'm struggling with, the main problem is the communication with the controller. The items i'm editing are rather complex and can't be rendered with an editorfor.

Comment: Ok so i implemented the example from stevenanderson.com. The strange thing is... it redirects me to a blank page with a new appointment row, instead of adding the empty row to the list.

Comment: Ok so far so good, it was missing the javascript, but now the nested list is empty when i submit my edit view.

Comment: If you update your question with your current solution I might be able to suggest a resolution, as it stands, any advice I give would not necessarily be relevant to your specific situation

Comment: Ive got it to work the steveanderson link did the trick. The only problem is that the performance is terrible.